# Added column to database, bound gridview not updating C#/winforms/SQL

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

I've set up a simple data bound gridview that is populated via the autogenerated code for winforms. It is filling based off of the dataset I point it at.

I've updated the underlying database it's supposed to be filling off of to add an additional column to a table. However this added column is not appearing in the gridview.

I have deleted the datset and rebound it and can't find an answer online but am probably searching with incorrect terms. Is there a way to refresh the dataset in some way?

How the gridview is being filled is by:

```
this.xTableAdapter.Fill(this.DBDataSet.tableName);
```

I imagine there is a simple way to refresh the underlying dataset but cannot for the life of me find what it is.

Comment: Are you sure ghe GridView has `AutoGenerateColumns` set to true? Is the new column in the DataSet when you check it with debugger?

Comment: The columns are autogenerating in the gridview and SELECT * FROM tableName returns the new column.

Comment: It does not appear that the new column is in the dataset on further debugging

Answer (score 0):

[This link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/cd16cf2d-5017-4659-adac-f689255670ff/refresh-dataset-for-new-fields?forum=winformsdatacontrols) had the answer. I needed to go into the dataset designer view and right click on the get, fill() query in the query area for my table. Doing so allowed me to modify the query that built the dataset, adding in the missing column.